# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_5 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
I am working in keras tensorflow on Windows 10
I tried a lot but could'nt find the missing dimension .
# Here is a snippet of my code with summary.

{
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( preprocessing_function=None)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'human_faces',
    target_size=(250,250),
     batch_size=3,
     class_mode='binary',classes=0)


# input_shape(no. of images/batch_size,height,width,channel(RGB))
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,batch_size=3, input_shape=(250,250,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(10)),
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(0.02))


#layer = Dropout(0.02)

#further layers:
model.add(Dense(units=5)) #hidden layer 1
model.add(Dense(units=4)) #output layer
#model.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(3,(3,3),input_shape=
(3,250,250,3),data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),input_shape=(3,250,250,3),
                       data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Dense(4,batch_size=3,input_shape=(124,124,3)))

model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer='sgd')

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

  test_generator = ImageDataGenerator()

validation_generator = test_generator.flow_from_directory(
    'human_faces/validation',
    target_size=(250,250),
    batch_size=3,
    class_mode=None,classes=0)

model.summary()
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=1,## batch_size,
        #steps_per_epoch=3,
        epochs=5,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
     #  validation_steps=61 )  # batch_size)
        validation_steps=1)
```

}

Found 61 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

dense_1 (Dense)              (3, 250, 250, 32)         128

---

activation_1 (Activation)    (3, 250, 250, 32)         0

---

dense_2 (Dense)              (3, 250, 250, 10)         330

---

activation_2 (Activation)    (3, 250, 250, 10)         0

---

dropout_1 (Dropout)          (3, 250, 250, 10)         0

---

dense_3 (Dense)              (3, 250, 250, 5)          55

---

dense_4 (Dense)              (3, 250, 250, 4)          24

---

conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (3, 248, 248, 3)          111

---

max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (3, 124, 124, 3)          0

---

## dense_5 (Dense)              (3, 124, 124, 4)          16

Total params: 664
Trainable params: 664
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Comment: Why do you have input_shape in layers beyond the first? That's probably your issue.

Comment: Sir I removed all the 'input_shape' in other layers but got the same error.